# Native speaker vs. Mother tongue speaker meaning

Tags: difference

Native speaker vs. Mother tongue speaker meaning

What are the differences between these  **two**  expression?

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: You might like to read the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language which gives a guide to the complexities of this issue and also a few alternative terms.

Comment: I am acquainted with several families where children were raised (and were fluent) in 3 languages, the father's, the mother's and that of the country in which they lived. In that context I would refer to **a native speaker of....**

Answer (score 1):

We say that a language is someone's 'mother tongue' rather than call them a 'mother tongue speaker'. It means that that is the language they first learned to talk in as a baby.

A 'native speaker' of a language is someone who was born into an environment where that language is spoken - so you see that they both mean the same thing.

Comment: Do we even really say "mother tongue" at all? It's understood, but I think "native language/speaker" is far more common. (Other languages certainly use their equivalent of "mother tongue/language"... French _langue maternelle_, German _Muttersprache_...)

Comment: We do use the phrase "mother tongue"  e.g "His mother tongue is Spanish".  We don't use the phrase "Mother tongue speaker".